# How to pass output to the xargs command by using piping and update user's plan after running the finger command

Tags: bash, shell-script, ubuntu

I'm a new user on Ubuntu and working on a task, but I haven't found any way to resolve this problem. Here is the statement:

> `finger` takes the user account name as the argument.  You can feed the user name to finger using the `whoami` command and piping the output to `xargs`.  The argument for `xargs` is, of course, the `finger` command.

I have done all the work and I know how to use the `finger` command but whenever I use `find . file.sh | xargs finger {username}`
I don't get the required result. Basically i want to run the one file .sh and then after .sh file the `finger` command should be run automatically. As like this screenshot [image]

Here is my code you can see this

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -n "What is your name? ";
read  name;

echo -n "Are you a (S)tudent or a (P)rofessor? ";
read  s_or_p

if [ $s_or_p = "P" -o $s_or_p = "p" ]; then

    student_or_professor="professor"
    research_or_scholastic="research"

    echo -n "Where do you work? ";
    read  workplace_or_college

    echo  "What are your top 3 research interests? ";
    read  interest1
    read  interest2
    read  interest3

    echo  "$name is a $student_or_professor that works at $workplace_or_college." >> ~/.plan


else 
    if [ $s_or_p = "S" -o $s_or_p = "s" ]; then
    student_or_professor="student"
    research_or_scholastic="scholastic"

    echo -n "Where do you attend? ";
    read  worksat_or_attends

    echo  "What are your top 3 scholastic interests? ";
    read  interest1
    read  interest2
    read  interest3
    echo  "$name is a $student_or_professor that attends $worksat_or_attends." >> ~/.plan

    fi
fi

echo "$name's $research_or_scholastic interests include:" >> ~/.plan;
echo  $interest1 >> ~/.plan
echo  $interest2 >> ~/.plan
echo  $interest3 >> ~/.plan

echo "Running finger on your account..."
find . planner.sh | xargs finger linux
```

Comment: i have completed the both tasks separately but i don't know how to run both from a single file and how to pass the output of .sh file to xargs command please help me ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your requirements state,

> You can feed the user name to `finger` using the `whoami` command and piping the output to `xargs`. The argument for `xargs` is, of course, the `finger` command.

You then yourself say that you use this command: `find . file.sh | xargs finger {username}` but that you don't get the required result.

The command you have designed doesn't match the criteria given in the requirement. Let's break that down:

> The argument for `xargs` is [...] the `finger` command

OK, so we have `xargs finger`. This requires input, and each line of input is appended to the end of the `finger` command by `xargs`.

> feed the user name to `finger` using the `whoami` command

We can't do `whoami | finger` (well we can, but it's meaningless as `finger` doesn't read from *stdin*), but we can apply the output of `whoami` to the end of the `finger` command like this:

```
whoami | xargs finger
```

That should answer the first part of your question. When you've used this and worked out what's missing in your second part perhaps you'd like to update your question with the new information.

Comment: i have completed the both tasks separately but i don't know how to run both from a single file and how to pass the output of .sh file to xargs command please help me.
I have made .sh file which will take the user data as like in the screen shot then after completing the user's input i want to give that output to the .paln file through xargs command and whenever i'll run the .sh file the .plan file should be run too.

Comment: @Error3735 you don't "run" a `.plan` file - it's just text. Please [update your question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/242239/edit) to explain properly what you are trying to achieve. Questions to consider: 1. if you're trying to run two commands in a script why can't you just put them on consecutive lines? 2. Why do you want to send the user's input through `xargs`? 3. What do you really mean by "running" the `.plan` file?

Comment: it's given in the description and the .pan file is a file when we run a command in a shell finger [username] then it shows all data of the login user and in the last it shows the mail and plan of the user.
Basically i want to update that plan.

Comment: Please check my code's last lines i have uploaded above with the screenshot.I want same out put after running my script file, i have a planner.sh file in which i'll ask questions to the user and then pass that output to variables to the .plan file like echo $interest1 >> ~/.plan so that when i'll run my file planner.sh that will show the updated plan of the finger command..

Comment: @Error3735 you want to run the script called `planner.sh`?

Comment: thanks sir my problem has been solved i have tried your given solution thanks a lot :)